# spotipy detect played-flag/status of a podcast episode

Tags: spotipy

How to detect the played-flag/status of a podcast episode via spotipy?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBtrm.png)

Workaround such as [episode duration - elapsed time] won't work because API doesn't have the info about elapsed time (only duration).

Answer (score 1):

resume_point in Get Episode (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-an-episode)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).